# Preparing for a throw, when forwarding ether to another contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-invocation

If a contract has a payable function, which forwards ether to another contract, but the second contract throws, how can you properly prepare for a throw in the first contract? Will the throw leave the money in the first contract, and if so can you return this money to the initial msg.sender?

Answer (score 1):

Very important to follow a safe three-step process.

1. Optimistic accounting (counter-intuitive but correct to do it first)
2. Try the send() and check the result (true or false).
3. On fail, either revert the accounting step-by-step, or `throw` (which reverts state changes including the account, returns the ETH and destroys the gas in one move.).

Example (Simplest interpretation I know with a full stop):

```
function forwardFunds(address recipient) payable returns(bool success) {
  LogForwarded(msg.sender, msg.value, recipient);
  if(!recipient.send(msg.value)) throw;
  return true; // doesn't make it this far in case of trouble
}
```

If the receiver `throws`, this function will `throw` as well, the `event` (i called it `LogForwarded`) that represents the "accounting" step will not occur and the received `msg.value` will be returned to `msg.sender`. Nevermind that the accounting event appears to come first, because `throw` will reliably revert that state change.

Check out "Reentrancy" and other stuff here: https://github.com/ConsenSys/smart-contract-best-practices. The three-step process above covers your concern and also synthesizes the know-how described (in the link) into a pattern I find easy to remember and apply consistently.

Hope it helps.